# can Json data be put into a value attribute so that it can be displayed in a form?

Tags: html, json

I have data thats coming to me in json and I have to put it into the text box so that it can be edited.

For example:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" value="{JsonObject.email}">
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case I have a json object that has data about a customer or employee and the form allows the user to edit the data in the form. How does one get this data into the value attribute when it is in Json?

Comment: Where is the jsonObject Server side or client side?

Comment: Yes, but you'd have to dynamically insert it into the form, and that is dependent on when you get your JsonObject.

Comment: it is pulled from the server by the client after the page is loaded

Answer (score 0):

solution:solution:

```
solution: $("#email").val(JsonObject.email);
```

Found at

http://api.jquery.com/val/